# Temporarily hide specific changes from Git

Tags: git

Occasionally I need to make changes to my codebase that I absolutely don't want to commit.  These may include:

- Urgent `TODO:` comments about things that *must* be done before I commit
- debugger statements
- temporary config file changes required to test something under different conditions
- changes made by my editor or linter that should be included in a separate commit

I realize that I can ignore entire *files* with [`git update-index --skip-worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_skip_worktree_bit) but that does me no good at all<sup>1</sup>.  The changes I want to skip are *almost always* in files that also have changes I *do* want to commit.  Is there any way to do this?

---

<sup>1</sup> And therefore also something that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45006289/temporarily-hide-some-changed-files-in-git) doesn't answer.

Comment: That looks a lot like 'committing changes you don' t want in a branch and check out back your current branch'. But something strange make that "you don't want to commit". Création and delete of commit is easy in git so don't hesitate!

Answer (score 3):

"Hide certain changes from git" *sounds* like it would address all of those situations, but you might reconsider if it's the *best* solution for any of them[1].

A manual approach would be to selectively stage changes.  This is done with the `-i` or `-p` option to `git add`.  (See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add for details of how to use these modes.)

Alternately you could do something with filters.  As long as the changes to be ignored can be identified by a script (such as using a regular expression to find some sort of tag you put on unwanted comments), then a clean filter can easily remove them.  The corresponding smudge filter is potentially harder, if you want subsequent checkouts to keep your local copy as it is.  (You could have the clean filter keep track of what it stored, and then have the smudge filter put it back... but there are potential complications, especially if you're collaborating with other developers.)  I think the `gitattributes` docs (under the `filter` attribute) would be the best place to start looking for info about this.  https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes

---

[1] If the TODO's have to be done before you commit, then hiding them from git (which suggests going ahead with the commit) defeats the point of the TODO comments.  Wouldn't it be better to reject commits containing such comments?  You could do that with a pre-commit hook, so long as your comments follow a predictable pattern.

If you just ignore debugger statements in the commit, then they presumably remain in your working copy (potentially to be forgotten and pile up there).  This is a more opinion-based question than the TODO's, but again wouldn't it be better to reminder yourself of the need to deal with them, rather than just ignore them?

The config file changes touches on a broader issue; my usual advice is to avoid source-controlling files that you might need to change locally.  Other ways to address that depend on your build tooling, though.

Comment: The filter is a great idea, and I generally wouldn't care about smudging back to how it was because these are only temporary changes.

Comment: selectively staging, however, is not a solution because the whole purpose of this is to exclude things _when I'm making the change_ so that **I don't have to think about it** _later when I'm staging changes_.

Comment: the pre-commit hooks are something I plan to do, but not really related to this question.  I gave those examples simply as _examples_ of *why* someone might want to ignore parts of files.  The examples are not ***themselves*** the problems I'm asking for help solving.   Same regarding the config file comment.

Comment: Could it be an option to commit these temporary changes with a specific prefix, and later on filter them out with a script?

Comment: That might work... commit any lines with (e.g.) `#← TEMP` and use a message with `TEMP:` at the beginning, and then rebase to remove all of the temporary commits. 